# Neo4j - graph not displayed

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am executing this query in the browser:

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) 
where (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
RETURN p, w, a, l, r, s, t;
```

The message I am getting is:

> Displaying 310 nodes, 669 relationships.

But no graph is shown.

When click on the Rows button I can see properly all the rows returned:

> Returned 223 rows in 690 ms.

Click back to the graph button, no graph shown there.

How I can get the graph shown on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried expanding the visualization window so the graph display takes up the entire window?

Also, try resetting your graph style sheet, just in case there is anything in there making the nodes difficult to see(???).  Do this by:

1. Click the star on the left hand menu
2. Click "Graph Style Sheet"
3. Click the firehose icon at the top right of the window that pops up (note: this will wipe out any customization to your visualization).

Comment: Did all 3 points suggested. No improvements. Here is something that returns less nodes and relationships: 16 nodes and 21 relationships. Still now graph displayed, only text. MATCH (w:Woka) WHERE (w.woka_title = 'Exile and the Kingdom') MATCH (a:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (p:Publisher)-[s:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) RETURN w, r, a, s, p, t, l;

Comment: I think you should work from the bottom up and start with visualizing just 1 node to remove the possibility for just about any other issue.  Just for kicks, click the icon on the left with the 3 bubbles (nodes).  I assume you see all of your labels, relationship types and property keys?      

Click the label * label.  It should visualize 25 nodes.  If that's not working, I would think you have a browser issue?

Comment: OK, I clicked all of them and got 25 nodes samples for: Author, Language, Publisher. Then I clicked on all relationships: AUTHORED, PUBLISHED and USED. Agains I got nice samples of 25 items or so. Not a problem here. The results are the same for all browsers used: Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Comment: Here is a the simplified return of the above query: MATCH (w:Woka) WHERE (w.woka_title = 'Exile and the Kingdom') MATCH (a:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (p:Publisher)-[s:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) RETURN w, a, p; The graph is shown in this case, but if I am adding another node in the RETURN, for example writing ,l between p and ; and the graph is no longer shown. Same result no matter the browser used.

Comment: More details, the query with 3 nodes in the RETURN has "Displaying 15 nodes, 14 relationships (completed with 14 additional relationships)." while the other one with 4 nodes in the return has "Displaying 16 nodes, 0 relationships.". How is this possible.

Comment: `MATCH (w:Woka) WHERE (w.woka_title = 'Exile and the Kingdom') MATCH (a:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (p:Publisher)-[s:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) RETURN w, a, p, l;`

`MATCH (w:Woka) WHERE (w.woka_title = 'Exile and the Kingdom') MATCH (a:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (p:Publisher)-[s:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka) MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) RETURN w, a, p;`

Comment: Recent development: after waiting 20 minutes the graph finally appeared on screen. So, what is causing this delays? The result set is retrieved from the database in 0.3 seconds. What takes so long to draw the graph?

Comment: I don't know how the nodes are drawn, so I can't speak to that, but I know that with very large result sets (over 500 nodes), it can take several minutes to render.  With a result of a thousand or more, I can be waiting a while.  I can't explain why your result set of a few dozen would take that long except that perhaps your computer is just really slow, old?  Or the way it's creating the nodes, it's just taking longer.  Do you notice general sluggishness on the computer while it's rendering?  Are you hosting the neo4j server on the same machine you're querying from?

Comment: For development I am using a Mac Book Pro 3GHz Intel i7 having 16GB of RAM. The database is hosted in an AWS server with 16GB of RAM. The network is 1Gbps. Each and every time the result set is larger I am using limit 100. The Neo4j database server has an 8GB memory allocation. We need to consider the fact that the results are retrieved in milliseconds while the graph is showing in tens of minuted or never.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Firefox, no matter how many nodes were being returned. It works fine using the Internet Explorer.

I could only solve it on Firefox turning off `AUTO-COMPLETE` (lower left of result pane) and repeating the query. Obviously the relationships will not be displayed automatically [:-|

Edit: found another solution (in my case): using a docker image with NEO4J instead of the Docker Toolbox for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax to display：

```
match p= (e)-[r:DO_SHOPPING_WITH]->(cc) return p
```

set the relationship to p, and then return p